# How to extract data beginning on the closest number to zero?

Tags: data

I have a list from which I want to extract only the values beginning from where `b` (from `{a,b}`) is the closest to zero. For example:

I want to extract

```
data={{2, -0.036704}, {56.7499, 0.95489}, {73.7349, 0.73489}, {2, -0.237504}}
```

from the following list:

```
list = {{1, 0.67342}, {77.7499, -0.93489}, {6.73448, 0.056704}, {2, -0.036704}, 
 {56.7499, 0.95489}, {73.7349, 0.73489}, {2, -0.237504}}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look up `Nearest`in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to find the index `ind` where the minimum occurs, and then take all the remaining elements of the list:

```
ind = First@Ordering[First@Abs[Rest[Transpose[list]]]];
list[[ind ;;]]
{{2, -0.036704}, {56.7499, 0.95489}, {73.7349, 0.73489}, {2, -0.237504}}
```

Comment: For long lists, the following may be faster `ind = First@ Ordering[Abs@ list[[All, 2]], 1]`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to find the starting index is to use [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest):

```
ind = First @ Nearest[Last @ Transpose @ list -> "Index", 0];
list[[ind;;]]
```

> {{2, -0.036704}, {56.7499, 0.95489}, {73.7349, 0.73489}, {2, -0.237504}}

For larger datasets, [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest) is faster:

```
data = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {10^6, 2}];
second = Last @ Transpose @ data;

r1 = First @ Nearest[second -> "Index", 0] //RepeatedTiming
r2 = First @ Ordering[Abs @ second, 1] //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.0018, 725110}
>
> {0.0062, 725110}